# Two autocomplete taking same data

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using two auto-complete using same source with filters for male and female but everytime I get male data only.

```
constructor() {
    this.familyMembers = familyMembers;
    this.husband = new FormControl();
    this.wife = new FormControl();
}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.wifeFilter = this.wife.valueChanges.pipe(
        startWith(''),
        map(value => this._filter(value, 'f'))
    );
    this.husbandFilter = this.husband.valueChanges.pipe(
        startWith(''),
        map(value => this._filter(value, 'm'))
    );
}

private _filter(value: string, gender: string): Person[] {
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();
    console.log(gender);
    let members = this.familyMembers.filter(option =>
        (option.maritalStatus.toLowerCase() === 'u' && option.gender.toLowerCase() == gender && option.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) === 0)
    );
    return members;
}
```

View page code.

```
<form class="example-form" class="example-full-width">

<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <mat-label>Pick one</mat-label>
    <input mat-input
         placeholder="Husband"
         aria-label="Members"
         matInput
         [formControl]="husband"
         [matAutocomplete]="auto">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let member of husbandFilter | async" [value]="member">
            {{ member.name }}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <mat-label>Wife</mat-label>
    <input mat-input
         placeholder="Wife"
         aria-label="Members"
         matInput
         [formControl]="wife"
         [matAutocomplete]="auto">
    <mat-autocomplete>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let member of wifeFilter | async" [value]="member">
            {{ member.name }}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple thing, To connect the input to autocomplete panel, previously (in my question) I tried with auto in one empty in other, they take same, Now I updated them. Its fine.

```
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <mat-label>Pick one</mat-label>
    <input mat-input
         placeholder="Husband"
         aria-label="Members"
         matInput
         [formControl]="husband"
         [matAutocomplete]="husband">
    <mat-autocomplete #husband="matAutocomplete">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let member of husbandFilter | async" [value]="member">
            {{ member.name }}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <mat-label>Wife</mat-label>
    <input mat-input
         placeholder="Wife"
         aria-label="Members"
         matInput
         [formControl]="wife"
         [matAutocomplete]="wife">
    <mat-autocomplete #wife="matAutocomplete">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let member of wifeFilter | async" [value]="member">
            {{ member.name }}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```